# jsp page is showing javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jsp

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>       org.apache.jsp.Officers.compose_005faction_jsp._jspService(compose_005faction_jsp.java:263)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

I am using netbeans 8.1 IDE.And I had already changed the vm option -Xmx512m . Still there is exception

Comment: Why don't you post your servlet code ?